# How to take only positive number in RadNumericTextBox?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to take only positive number in my RadNumericTextBox.

I tried

```
    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox MinValue="0" TabIndex="8" ID="txtPositiveNumericField" runat="server" Width="98%">
           <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" /> 
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

But till now it takes negative number.

Answer (score 3):

What Telerik library version are you using? In my case, all I needed to do is
just apply `MinValue` attribute and set it to 0. I added `DataType` attribute as well, just to be specific about what type of numeric value I want.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox MinValue="0" TabIndex="8" DataType="System.Int32" ID="txtPositiveNumericField" runat="server" Width="98%">
       <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution by using javascript function.
Add ClientEvents for OnKeyPress in RadNumericTextBox and for this event define a javascript function.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox MinValue="0" TabIndex="8" ID="txtPositiveNumericField" runat="server" Width="98%">
       <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
       <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="NumberFieldKeyPress" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

And javascript function:

```
function NumberFieldKeyPress(obj ,arg)
        {
            if(arg.get_keyCode()==45)
            {
                alert("This field only takes positive number.");
                arg.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
```

But if there have any trick without javascript please put your answer.

Thanks ..